# Responsive header not opening or closing header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a responsive header for a website I'm creating and I'm not getting this output where when my browser gets small enough the bars icon comes up to press. But for some reason when I try to open up the menu it does not work. I'm looking for some help on this I can't seem to figure it out as I'm not very knowledgeable in JavaScript, CSS, HTML.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/headercss2.css">
    <script src="javascript/script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo" src="images/logo_trans.png" alt="logo" style="height: 75px;">
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services
                            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Business Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Canvas Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Embroidery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Signs</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Partners</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="move-right btn">
                        <a href="#">Cart</a>
                    </li>
                    
                
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.containter {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 117rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons{
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    display: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225,225,225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border: 2px solid #1E90FF;
    border-radius: 5rem;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 650ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
    
li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display:none;
        align-items: initial;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .nav-list li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }
    
    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #00BFFF;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
    }
    
    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }
    
    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }
    
    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .fas fa-times {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-times{
        display: block;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-bars{
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display:flex;
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement('.menu-icons').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement{'nav').classList.toggle('active');
);
```

Comment: ```selectElement{'nav').classList.toggle('active');``` ---> ```selectElement('nav').classList.toggle('active');```

Comment: you added { inded of ( in selectElement{'nav').classList.toggle('active');

Comment: Omg I can't believe I missed that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `{` where you should have a `(`:

```js
document.querySelector('.menu-icons').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.containter {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 117rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  border: 2px solid #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 5rem;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #00BFFF;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 16rem;
  transition: all 650ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
  top: .9rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #00BFFF;
  top: 0;
  left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  line-height: initial;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00BFFF;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
  }
  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: initial;
  }
  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }
  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }
  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }
  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="menu-icons">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i> text
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo_trans.png" alt="logo" style="height: 75px;">
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Services
                            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                        </a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Business Printing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Canvas Printing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Embroidery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Signs</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Partners</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>

        <li class="move-right btn">
          <a href="#">Cart</a>
        </li>


      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!